# How to hide content on certain pages and not others via a Master Page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Read this thread but didn't really answer my question and there were quite a few suggestions so not sure if they are on the right track:  [Master Page content filtering with respect to asp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893239/master-page-content-filtering-with-respect-to-asp-page)

What I have is a site with 1 Master Page and in it is a global footer that all pages use. I want to eliminate the footer on only 1 page (i.e. the login page) but keep all the other master page content intact.

I know I could create a separate Master Page just for this login page but it seems overkill. Is there a way to put in some logic that if it's only this specific page that it would hide the footer and then show on every other page?

Thanks for any tips/suggestions.

Edit: There was already a Page Load sub in the code behind. All I had to add was - `MasterPage_Footer.Visible = False` on the If statement when users were not logged in and set it to `True` when they were logged in. Works like a charm. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Is your footer in a separate server-side control from the other information on the master page (like a `ContentPlaceHolder`)?

Comment: Can't you obtain your **pagename** at run time?? Then you can add a css class to the container which holds the **footer**... something like **Path.GetFileName(request.PhysicalPath)**

Comment: @jadarnel27 yes, the footer is in a `ContentPlaceHolder` tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expose a property on the MasterPage to allow content pages to override default behavior if needed.

In the MasterPage:

```
private bool showFooter = true;

public bool ShowFooter { get {return showFooter;} set {showFooter = value;} }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    footerControl.Visible = showFooter;
}
```

Make sure content pages that need to access the property have the following line in the aspx:

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="XXX" %>
```

and in the content pages code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Master.ShowFooter = false;
}
```

Comment: @Tim, MasterType creates a strongly typed reference to the Master Page class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: This worked for me, except for an issue where reloading would cause the control to go null, so I worked around it by doing a null check and then just adding `var newCtl = new FooterControl();` and all was well

Answer (score 1):

In your MasterPage:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
   FooterControl.Visible = HttpRequest.IsAuthenticated && !(page is LoginPage)
}
```

- [HttpContext.Handler Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.handler.aspx)
- [is (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)